# Newbie SQL syntax query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query against database table h_cmdb_assets to return a count of and entries for h_owned_by_name that do have a name against them but only if h_record_state is Active or Operational (0 or 1) but the query fails.

I am just learning SQL and am unsure as to whether you can use 2 WHERE commands or whether I just have the syntax wrong.

I am not using MYSQL to run this query but I am using it within the database direct query function of our ITSM tool - Hornbill Service Manager.

I am using:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM h_cmdb_assets
 WHERE h_record_state in ('0','1') 
    or h_operational_state in ('0','1')
   AND 
 WHERE h_owned_by_name is null 
    or h_owned_by_name =' '
 order 
    by count(*) desc
```

Any pointers gratefully received.

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Only one WHERE for each FROM clause. Use AND or OR.

Comment: Remember that AND has higher precedence. `a AND b OR c` means `(a AND B) or c`

Comment: `that do have a name against them` then why are you searching for `h_owned_by_name is null`? Did you miss NOT as in: `that do NOT have a name against them`?

Comment: Still struggling

Comment: @AndrewL What message does the query fails with now after you've implemented all the recommendations?

Comment: @jarlh So you can have multiple FROM clauses?

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, if you have subqueries or UNION/INTERSECT etc.

Comment: @ekocherin - unfortunately I am not afforded with a constructive error message and being so new to the SQL game I really am struggling to understand how to use the various titbits of advice into a meaningful query. From the detail provided is there anyone that could suggest what my query should be please?

Comment: Please share more details - what do you want to achieve? What **exactly** are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` is a clause that is allowed at most one time per `SELECT`.

> I am trying to query against database table h_cmdb_assets to return a count of and entries for h_owned_by_name that do have a name against them but only if h_record_state is Active or Operational (0 or 1)

What you are looking for is more complex boolean logic:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM h_cmdb_assets
WHERE h_record_state in (0, 1) AND
      (h_owned_by_name IS NULL OR h_owned_by_name = '');
```

Notes:

- The question only references `h_record_state`, not `h_operational_state`, so I removed that.  I assume the `0` and `1` refer to active/operational.
- `0` and `1` look like numbers.  Compare numbers to numbers and strings to strings.  Try not to mix types.
- You use `' '` for a blank string.  I think `''` is more likely.  If you want to eliminate spaces as well, then you can use `trim()` or `replace(name, ' ', '') = '')`.
- An aggregation query with no `ORDER BY` always returns exactly one row.  The `ORDER BY` is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, we have two states. I ran your query (for which I greatly appreciate your time) but it failed to execute. So, made slight amendments:

SELECT count(*) FROM h_cmdb_assets
WHERE h_record_state in ('2') AND h_operational_state in ('2')
AND h_owned_by_name IS NULL OR h_owned_by_name = ' '

2 being the ID for Archived & Retired (instead of 0 & 1) and the result was a count of 2 for records without an Owner but upon investigation these database records are both Archived and Retired so should have been filtered out with the logic.